# How to get WebStorm code completion when using a WebPack built bundle from HTML file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webstorm, code-completion

Let's start with my example `src/index.js` file:

```
export function foobar() {}
```

The WebPack config:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      library: 'MyBundle',
    },
  }
]
```

When running `webpack` the `dist/bundle.js` is created.

I create a new WebStorm project and an `index.html` file in which I load the bundle with `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`

Now, if I type `MyBundle.` there is no completion.

But if I open the `index.html` file in a Browser, and type in the dev console `MyBundle.`, there is a completion for `foobar()` function.

Is there a way to get the same completion in WebStorm ? I tried with source map with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyBundle` is available in runtime, but there is no such object in your source code, and the generated bundle is excluded from indexing for better performance/navigation/etc. Resolving it during static code analysis requires providing special support for the way webpack exposes libraries, namely for its `output.library` property. If you miss it, feel free to file a feature request to [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB).

For now, I can only suggest using JSDoc annotations to let the IDE know about your library. Like:

```
/**
 * @namespace MyBundle
 */

/**
 * @memberOf MyBundle
 */
export function foobar() {}
```

Comment: I understand. Clever and better than nothing (it requires to not use optimization, since this option removes the comments).